# Load stream with file

Tags: c++-cli

How can I load a stream with a file contents?

```
Stream^ data; // How to load this with file contents?
```

I want to load this stream with a file on my hard drive.

Comment: I found [a search query that may be helpful](https://www.google.com/#psj=1&q=load+stream+with+file+contents+C%2B%2B).

Comment: You are probably not using a standard C++. With C++03 or C++11 just use [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/basic_istream)....

Comment: data = gcnew FileStream(...)

Comment: FileStream creates a stream of type FileStream. How can I convert it to type Stream?

Comment: @user2696323 If you look at the inheritance hierarchy in the [first reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) given by @SteveL, you'll see that `FieStream` *is a* 'Stream`.

Comment: when I try try { Stream^ data = gcnew FileStream("C:\\Secure\\Source\\cutlas\\Core\bin\\TestData.xml",FileMode::OpenOrCreat‌​e); } catch (const exception &e) { const char* exp = e.what(); getManager()->log(exp,HIGH_IMPORTANCE); } I get an error "unable to access invalid memory location"

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3352a4t.aspx) and a high level overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx). The examples for the latter are in C# and VB, but are easily translate-able into C++/CLI.